# SAPUI5: Create multiple forms for display based on number of elements in an array

Tags: sapui5

I have an array which has too many fields to display inside a table. So, I was wondering, is it possible to have a pre-defined Form that can be generated dynamically for display? For example, if my array has 10 elements, 10 forms will be displayed to the user one under the next.
If this is possible what is the best way to achieve it? Eg. do we need to use a Component Container or Fragment? Thanks for your guidance.

D.

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like [XML Templates](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/5ee619fc1370463ea674ee04b65ed83b) or build the depending UI part inside the controller.